# How to run FZF in vim in a directory where the directory path comes from a function?

Tags: vim, fzf

I'd like to run fzf file finder (inside vim) on a custom directory, but the directory name varies at runtime.

For e.g., say, vim is started at the root of project directory. The subdirectories look like:

```
$ tree -ad
.
├── docs
├── .notes
│   ├── issue_a
│   └── new_feature
├── README
├── src
└── tests
```

Every time I create a branch, I also create a directory in `.notes/BRANCH_NAME` where I store notes, tests results, etc. The `.notes` directory itself is ignored by git.

I'd like to run FZF on the `.notes/BRANCH_NAME` directory. The branch name will come from a function (say using https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch).

I am able to run fzf on the `.notes` directory by `:FZF .notes`, but I don't know how to run it on the branch directory within `.notes`.

Thanks!

**Edit:** Added what I'd tried:

I tried saving the output of `gitbranch#name()` to a variable and then use it to call `fzf#run()`, but didn't quite work:

```
function! NotesDir()
    let branch=gitbranch#name()
    let ndir=".notes/" . branch
    call fzf#run({'source': ndir})
endfunction
command! NotesDir call NotesDir()
```

When I run `:NotesDir` while on branch `issue_a`, I see `fzf` window with an error:

```
>   < [Command failed: .notes/issue_a]
```

`.notes/issue_a` indicates that `ndir` variable has the correct notes directory path, but I couldn't figure out how to pass it to fzf.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl updated the original question to include what I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation for `fzf#run()`](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/blob/master/README-VIM.md#fzfrun), it looks like `source` could be either a *string*, interpreted as a shell command to execute, or a *list*, used as-is to populate the plugin's window.

So your mistake was passing a path as `source`, which was interpreted as an external command, instead of either an external command or a list of paths.

It also says that you should at least provide a `sink` but some examples don't have it so YMMV.

If I am reading that section correctly, the following approaches should work:

```
" with a string as external command
call fzf#run({'source': 'find ' .. ndir, 'sink': 'e'})

" with a list
let list = globpath('.', ndir, O, 1)
           \ ->map({ _, val -> val->fnamemodify(':.')})
call fzf#run({'source': list, 'sink': 'e'})
```

NOTE: I don't use that plugin so this is not tested.

Comment: `call fzf#run({'source': 'find ' .. ndir, 'sink': 'e'})` works fine. Thanks.